# Rails - Bootstrap popover js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to understand how js works in Rails.

I am using bootstrap and have managed to get popovers working, but not in the way that i had understood Rails works.

I currently have a partial called _preferences inside my organisations views folder. In my organisations show page, I render that partial. The partial has a button which calls a popover, as:

```
 <button class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x fa-border btn-info" id="publicity" href="#"  rel="popover" data-original-title="Publicity Issues" data-content="<%= publicity_popover(@organisation.preference)%>"></button>
```

I tried to make an organisations.js file that had:

```
$('#publicity').popover()
$('#academic_publication').popover()
$('#presentations').popover()
```

but the popovers didn't work when I tried that approach.

When I add the following to the bottom of the preferences partial, it all works fine.

```
<script>
$('#publicity').popover()
$('#academic_publication').popover()
$('#presentations').popover()
</script>
```

I expected the first attempt to work. I can't understand why it doesnt. Does any one see the error?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using **turbolinks** that's way.The file that you have created is being fetched at the head of the document `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`
 which is a bad practice, if you would use turbolinks properly then your app would be faster. In the application.js add:

```
ready = function(){
$('#publicity').popover();
$('#academic_publication').popover();
$('#presentations').popover();
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Read more on https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic

Comment: I have turbolinks => false (because i use olark)

Comment: If you have turbolinks off, again the file that you have created is being fetched at the head of the document and turbolinks aren't tracked so the script won't run properly in time that the page loads.

Comment: I understand that you are using olark but that doesn't mean taht you shouldn't use turbolinks there are comaptability scripts. https://www.olark.com/help/turbolinks

Comment: is there a way to make it work with turbo links turned off?

Comment: @user2860931 Link <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %> at the bottom of the page not in the head.